# MAME "distributions": which one is better for what thing?

Tags: arcade, emulation, windows-xp, mame

I've used [MAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAME) almost from the beginning of the project and love it. But today there exist so many variations and "distributions" of the original that I can't keep count. I used the [MAME Plus](http://mameicons.free.fr/mame32p/) project but today I like the [MAME Plus! XT](http://www.mamext.net) a little more. I'm looking for a version that uses a multicore processor better, but any suggestions would be appreciated. I also prefer the ones that keep up-to-date with the original project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 main versions which together will play pretty much everything. For the official MAME, get MameUI64: this version has a nice user interface and is 64bit. Winkawaks is used for some Capcom games which run on a different chipset to MAME.

Everything else seems to built on top of these two.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in submitting high scores to Twin Galaxies, [you'll need to use WolfMAME](http://forums.twingalaxies.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=25671): the version from which they are currently accepting scores is [0.106](http://wolfmame.marpirc.net/). (Yes, it's five years old, and the current version is 0.142, but it's their site and their rules.)